# Why is R merging all the rows in my CSV file as one whole document?

Tags: r, tm

I am using `R` for a sentiment analysis. My source file which contains around 50 reviews made by guests has been created in `Excel` (with each review recorded in a single row and single column). So, all reviews are found in Column A, with no headers. The file has then been saved as a `csv` file and stored in a folder.

My `R` codes are as follows:

```
library (tm)
docs<-Corpus(DirSource('E:/Sentiment Analysis'))
#checking a particular review in the document
writeLines(as.character(docs[[20]]))
```

Running that last line gives me an out of bound error message.
When I change it to `writeLines(as.character(docs[[1]]))`, R displays all the reviews as if they were one whole paragraph.

How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tm::Corpus()` function used with `DirSource()` treats each file as a separate document, rather than each line within one file as a separate document.

To read each row of a text file as a separate document, one can use the `Corpus(VectorSource())` syntax.

As an example, we'll create a text file, read it from a directory to illustrate how `Corpus()` behaves with `DirSource()`, versus how we would read it with `VectorSource()`.

```
# represent contents of the text file that was stored in 
# ./data/ExcelFile1.csv
aTextFile <- "This is line one of text.
This is line two of text. This is a second sentence in line two."

library(tm)
# read as the OP read it
corpusDir <- "./data/textMining"
aCorpus <- Corpus(DirSource(corpusDir))
length(aCorpus) # shows only one item in list, entire file

# use pipe as separator because documents include commas. 
aDataFrame <- read.table("./data/textMining/ExcelFile1.csv",header=FALSE,
                         sep="|",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# use VectorSource to treat each row as a separate document
aCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(aDataFrame$V1))
# print the two documents 
aCorpus[1]$content
aCorpus[2]$content
```

...and the output. First, the length of the corpus as we read it with `DirSource()`:

```
> length(aCorpus) # shows only one item in list, entire file
[1] 1
```

Second, we'll print the two rows from the second read, illustrating that they are treated as separate documents.

```
> aCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(aDataFrame$V1))
> aCorpus[1]$content
[1] "This is line one of text."
> aCorpus[2]$content
[1] "This is line two of text. This is a second sentence in line two. "
>
```